# Giving haircut to parent

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Is there a problem with a child giving his/her father or mother a haircut from the aspect of kibud av v'eim? Is there also a concern that one might "nick" the skin in the process and cause a wound?

Comment: `libido av v'eim`?